# How can I print every input from "for i in range" function in one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want to do is to write a program which first tells you to type a number (let's say 4), and then it tells you to name 4 capital cities in the world . In order to do that, I need to use "for i in range" function, right?. But after for i in range, how can I have all those names printed on the same line? I'm using python 3.4.4

Here's an attempt:

[PythonTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TGGz.jpg)

Comment: Can you post an attempt?

Comment: You can print them in just a line in the first try. Trust me!